# How to force ubuntu to Fix root directory without interacting with user while booting up?

Tags: boot, filesystem, disk, ext4, fdisk

I'm using ubuntu on an industrial board ([beaglebone black](https://beagleboard.org/black)). Sometimes as the result of power failure or other issues, when booting up the os asks to press F to fix the root partition and waits there till the user does something. But I want to make sure the os boots up because there is no user available there to press any button, actually there is no serial cable connected to my embedded board so that anyone can send any character to it.

How can ubuntu be configured so that It would always fix the filesystem without asking the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-a` argument.

```
fsck /dev/sdaX -a -p
```

`$ man fsck`

Taken from the man pages:

```
   Options  to  different filesystem-specific fsck's are not standardized.
   If in doubt, please consult the man pages  of  the  filesystem-specific
   checker.   Although not guaranteed, the following options are supported
   by most filesystem checkers:

   -a     Automatically repair the filesystem without any  questions  (use
          this  option with caution).  Note that e2fsck(8) supports -a for
          backward compatibility only.  This option is mapped to  e2fsck's
          -p  option  which is safe to use, unlike the -a option that some
          filesystem checkers support.

   -n     For some filesystem-specific checkers, the -n option will  cause
          the fs-specific fsck to avoid attempting to repair any problems,
          but simply report such problems to stdout.  This is however  not
          true  for  all  filesystem-specific  checkers.   In  particular,
          fsck.reiserfs(8) will not report any corruption  if  given  this
          option.  fsck.minix(8) does not support the -n option at all.

   -r     Interactively  repair  the  filesystem  (ask for confirmations).
          Note: It is generally a bad idea to use this option if  multiple
          fsck's  are  being  run  in  parallel.   Also  note that this is
          e2fsck's default behavior; it supports this option for  backward
          compatibility reasons only.

   -y     For  some filesystem-specific checkers, the -y option will cause
          the fs-specific fsck to  always  attempt  to  fix  any  detected
          filesystem corruption automatically.  Sometimes an expert may be
          able to do better driving the fsck manually.  Note that not  all
          filesystem-specific checkers implement this option.  In particu‐
          lar fsck.minix(8) and  fsck.cramfs(8)  do  not  support  the  -y
          option as of this writing.
```

**The quick help screen shows:**

```
Emergency help:
 -p                   Automatic repair (no questions)
 -n                   Make no changes to the filesystem
 -y                   Assume "yes" to all questions
 -c                   Check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list
 -f                   Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean
 -v                   Be verbose
 -b superblock        Use alternative superblock
 -B blocksize         Force blocksize when looking for superblock
 -j external_journal  Set location of the external journal
 -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list
 -L bad_blocks_file   Set badblocks list
```

**Other related items:**

the `/etc/fstab` calls the `/etc/init.d/checkfs.sh` for it's checking.  You can edit that file to give it the parameters you want.

**Check these blocks:**

```
[ "$fscheck" = yes ] && log_warning_msg "Fast boot enabled, so skipping file system check."
```

`if [ "$fscheck" = yes ] && [ ! "$BAT" ] && [ "$FSCKTYPES" != "none" ]`

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that when the kernel is booting up it finds some errors in root (/) partition and asks to press F to fix them, and waits there for user to press a button without any timeout. can i pass something maybe to fstab so that when the kernel wants to mount the root partition fix automatically if there is any errors?

Comment: @hmojtaba What do you have in the 6th field of the `/etc/fstab` line?  I'm sure having the field blank or a `0` will indicate to the system it doesn't need to be checked and will skip.  If you're asking how to have it check and pass the autofix via the `/etc/fstab` line, I don't think there is one for that.  You could create  a  script to perform a quick check and notify you if the filesystem needs to be check, then you could manually check it.  I'll research for more on that and update my answer with what I find.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I need the partition to be scanned so the last field is not 0 but is 1. If there was at least a timeout that if a user did not press any button, it would fix it automatically or even skip fixing and mount the root partition and continue booting the os! it's an embedded os which will be used as a product! The last thing i want is the ubuntu to stop there asking a user to press a button when there is no user to do that!

Comment: @hmojtaba I appended my answer at the bottom (other related items).   See if that will help.

Comment: Thanks to the hints in your answer I found related parameters (like `"$fscheck" = yes`) not in `/etc/init.d/checkfs.sh` ( there was no such file but another file in `/etc/init/checkfs.sh.conf` ...) but something similar to that in `/etc/default/rcS` named `FSCKFIX=no` then i changed it to `FSCKFIX=yes`. I have not tested if it is working or not, will let you know about the results. OH i just found other stuff in `/etc/init/mountall.conf` ... wait for my nest edit

Comment: I looked up `/etc/init/mountall.conf` description indicating "Mount filesystem on boot" there seems to be some options there! within the main script it runs the `/etc/default/rcS` file, and I changed something inside that file (mentioned in my previous comment). I hope it works.

Comment: @hmojtaba I'm hoping that you have backed up the files that you changed.  The `FSCKFIX=no` to `yes` isn't an `fsck` argument.  It's a decision whether to `fsck` or not.  You want it to check the disk.  It's the options that you want to set for when the `fsck` is run.  The arguments are in the `etc/init/checkfs.sh`.

Comment: @hmojtaba On further study, the `/etc/default/rcS` is likely the key.  Those parameters are passed to the `/etc/init.d/checkfs.sh` file.  Do you remember which change you made?  I can post the 25 line default file if you like, then you  can compare the difference.  I usually back up a configuration file before making changes so that if something breaks I can revert.

Comment: that's good, this way the problem is solved. and yes I made a backup before making the changes. Thank you for the answer.